# highcharts animation multiple spline per second

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'll go for a graph with two line live data.
Just need to send them data each second.

But animation go wrong !

here the event for add data per second

```
events: {
                load: function () {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    var bis = this.series[1];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                        bis.addPoint([x,0.5], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
```

here the code of base line

```
series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.random()
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }())
        },
        {
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.random()
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
```

here the fiddle ! http://jsfiddle.net/g6ga6r5c/

I ve try other way, duplicate event, etc but i don t know how i can fix that :/

Thx for help

---

build this with doc line per second doc by highcharts -> http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update/grid-light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're adding more than one point, you need to ensure only the last point you add tells the chart to redraw itself. This is what the second parameter on the `addPoint` function does:

> #### **`addPoint`** (Object `options`, [Boolean `redraw`], [Boolean `shift`], ...)
>
> - `redraw`: Boolean
>     Defaults to `true`. Whether to redraw the chart after the point is added. When adding more than one point, it is highly recommended that the `redraw` option be set to false, and instead `chart.redraw()` is explicitly called after the adding of points is finished.
>
> — [Series.addPoint() on Highcharts API documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.addPoint())

To fix your code, simply set this second parameter to `false` when adding your first point:

```
series.addPoint([x, y], false, true);
bis.addPoint([x,0.5], true, true);
```

[Amended JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g6ga6r5c/1/).